# Matlab filter() with SciPy lfilter()

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

According to their documentation for [Matlab filter()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/filter.html) and [SciPy lfilter()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.10.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html), it seems like they should be "compatible". However I have a problem, porting larger Matlab code in Python, for which I get `ValueError: object of too small depth for desired array`. As I can't think of how I can present my source without complicating it, I'll use the example provided in Matlab's documentation:

```
data = [1:0.2:4]';
windowSize = 5;
filter(ones(1,windowSize)/windowSize,1,data)
```

which I translate in Python to:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import lfilter

data = np.arange(1, 4.1, 0.2)
windowSize = 5
lfilter(np.ones((1, windowSize)) / windowSize, 1, data)
```

In this case I get:
`ValueError: object too deep for desired array`

Why do I get these errors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is there a reason you're adding a an extra dimension when creating your array of ones? Is this what you need:

```
lfilter(np.ones(windowSize) / windowSize, 1, data)
```

Comment: There is no reason, just my ignorance :) I didn't spotted that while translating. Thanks

Comment: ah yes I remember now, in matlab ones(10) returns a 10 by 10, oh those good old matlab days.