# How to smooth 3D data set based on a given axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, smoothing

I have a 3D data set. X1 and X2 are contentious variables and the X3 (Outcome variable) is binary. The data are shown in the figure.
I would like to smooth the data (kind of local averaging)[3D data points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WY88K.png) on the X3 axis. I mean for a given X1 and X2, the X3 variable instead of binary, should be a number between 0 and 1. For example, when X1=1100 and X2=3.5, the X3 should be a value between 0 and 1. 
I appreciated your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matlab filter() with SciPy lfilter()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922657/matlab-filter-with-scipy-lfilter)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is super unclear. Are you wanting the third variable to have a random distribution between 0 and 1, or do you want the 3rd variable to follow some curve based on variables 1 and 2? Anyway, here is an example of generating some random data, between 0 and 1.

```
import numpy as np 

X1 = <some data>
X2 = <some data>
X3 = np.random.random(100)
```

EDIT:

Now that I understand you want to average over repeats. You could just loop over your data. Like,

```
repeats = {}
for n,(x,y) in enumerate(zip(X1,X2)):
    repeats[(x,y)] = repeats.get((x,y),[]) + [X3[n]]
repeats = {k:sum(v)/len(v) for k,v in repeats.items()}
```

Of course if you want your code to be much more efficient and faster you could use numpy.

Comment: Sorry if the question is unclear. I want to curve based on variables 1,2, and 3. I want to average variable 3 based on variables 1 and 2. suppose we have two data points which have same values for X1 and X2. But for the first point, X3=0 and for the second one X3=1. So the average X3 is 0.5 for the corresponding X1 and X2.

Comment: So are you saying there are repeats in your data and you want to average on the repeats? The picture did not at all convey that there were repeats.

Comment: Yes exactly. There are overlapping between the upper and the bottom plane.